# Closure semantics in Python generator comprehensions

Tags: python, closures, list-comprehension, generator, semantics

In the following code I get `([1], [1])` for `l1` but `([0], [1])` for `l2, l3, l4`. Which I find surprising, especially the difference between using `t` in the `in` clause (`l3, l4`), where it makes no difference whether it's a generator comprehension or a list comprehension, vs in the `if` clause (`l1, l2`), where it does.

```
l1 = [(x for x in (0, 1) if x == t) for t in (0, 1)]
l2 = [[x for x in (0, 1) if x == t] for t in (0, 1)]
l3 = [(x for x in [t]) for t in (0, 1)]
l4 = [[x for x in [t]] for t in (0, 1)]
print([(*map(list, l),) for l in (l1, l2, l3, l4)])
```

May I ask you for a detailed explanation of the rules governing such expressions? A link to relevant documentation? A rationale?

Comment: I strongly advise against writing code that depends on such semantics.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I noticed it accidentally, solving Day 13 of Advent of Code 2021. To follow your advice, or make my own informed opinion on the set of advisable practices, I need to understand clearly what's going on. Otherwise I wouldn't even know when I'm about to write something you suggest avoiding.

Comment: From a deleted answer (but may be helpful to understand better):
Try any other list:

>>> l1 = [(x for x in (0, 1, 2) if x == t) for t in (0, 1, 2)]
>>> (*map(next, l1),)
(2, 2, 2)
My comment:
    Sure it's (2, 2, 2), my use case indeed has more values, I extracted its essence for the question. Your answer was my first guess as well, but it still doesnt explain the difference between l1 and l3. And the exact scope in which t lives in each case remains elusive.

Comment: "Otherwise I wouldn't even know when I'm about to write something you suggest avoiding." Just don't close over mutable values if you don't need to?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, it's not obviously mutable, there's no assignment (simple or compound) operator in sight. And if you mean that any code with deferred evaluation (including generators) shouldn't reference mutable variables (including control variables of `for` loops, be it in `for` statements or any type of comprehension), then it's a very far fetching restriction. Not that I strongly oppose your advice, just trying to weigh pros and cons; maybe afterwards I'll share your conclusion. But anyway, for this question it's a tangential discussion.

Comment: Actually your disclaimer "if you don't need to" makes it a milder statement than your initial "I strongly advise against", so I can add that in general I already agree with you.  Cheers!

Comment: IMX, programmers are biased towards overestimating how often they "need to" do un-straightforward things.

Comment: That's also true. But – returning to the question – deeper understanding the language makes them in many cases more likely to realize that a straightforwarder solution is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute

```py
l1 = [(x for x in (0, 1) if x == t) for t in (0, 1)]
```

`l1` is a list of generators, each one holding a reference to *the same* "captured" variable `t`. When `l1[0]` is created, the value of `t` is 0, but the generator is not yet evaluated. When `l1[1]` is created, the value of `t` is 1, and is not modified afterwards. you can check this using:

```
c1 = l1[0]
c2 = l1[1]
print(c1.gi_frame.f_locals)
print(c2.gi_frame.f_locals)
print(c1.gi_frame.f_locals['t'] is c2.gi_frame.f_locals['t'])
```

As for why this does not happen in `l3`, I understand that in order to build
the generators, their limits must be evaluated, so `[t]` must be evaluated
and a list created at the moment of creating the generator. A modified script that helps to understand what happens follows (the original code commented out to facilitate the comparison):

```py
def testequal(x, t):
    print(f"Called with x={x}, t={t}")
    return x == t

def generate_limits():
    print("Creating limits")
    return (0, 1)

def generate_list(t):
    print(f"creating list with t={t}")
    rv = [t,]
    return rv

print("Creating l1...")
# l1 = [(x for x in (0, 1) if x == t) for t in (0, 1)]
l1 = [(x for x in generate_limits() if testequal(x,t)) for t in (0, 1)]
print("Creating l2...")
l2 = [[x for x in (0, 1) if x == t] for t in (0, 1)]
print("Creating l3...")
# l3 = [(x for x in [t]) for t in (0, 1)]
l3 = [(x for x in generate_list(t)) for t in (0, 1)]
print("Creating l3...")
l4 = [[x for x in [t]] for t in (0, 1)]
print("Evaluating..." )
print([(*map(list, l),) for l in (l1, l2, l3, l4)])
```

Comment: Yup, that's it! I came up with the same explanation (including the rationale) using this code (which traces the sequence of evaluation, similarly to yours) to verify: https://github.com/ByteEater-pl/WriteCodeAlmostEveryDay/blob/master/Python/closures%20in%20generator%20comprehensions.py. But, as I usually do (I apparently already have too much reputation for me answering my own questions to increase it), I waited for some time to see if anybody gives an answer, possibly even better than I would. So thanks and kudos!

Comment: Furthermore, [PEP 289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) actually does have the details. It specifies the semantics of generator expressions as equivalent to generator functions obtained by a syntactic transformation. It uses the `for` loop for which the caveat with references (including in closures) is widely known in many languages.